# Python telebot запускается определенная функция, а не случайная

Tags: python, функции, telebot

Всегда запускается одна функция "test_funks1", а я хочу чтобы запуская рандомная

```
    elif (message.text == 'Игра "Угадай число"'):
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Ну... Давай начнем, я загадал случайное слово(арбуз,дыня,яблоко,вишня)")
        igra(message)

def igra(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Я в тебя верю")
    my_list=[test_funks1 or
             test_funks2 or
             test_funks3 or
             test_funks4
             ]
    bot.register_next_step_handler(message, random.choice(my_list))
```

Comment: Зачем `or`? Просто поставь запятые

Comment: Пробовал, все равно такая же проблема, так что проблема не в этом

Comment: С `or` точно не будет работать как вы хотите. Вы в `random.choice` сейчас передаете список из одного элемента, т.к. результатом `or` от не falsy значений будет первое значение, т.е. `[test_funks1 or test_funks2 or test_funks3 or test_funks4]` превратится просто в `[test_func1]`. С запятыми по идее должно работать, проверьте еще раз.